# Where does the name node resides in RAM or in Hard disk?

Tags: hadoop

Where does the name node resides in RAM or in Hard disk - Hadoop 1.2.1?

The Name node daemon is placed in RAM or in the Secondary memory. Can any one please help to know this?

Comment: Namenode:The core metadata server of Hadoop.This is the most critical piece of the system, and there can only be one of these.This stores both the file system image and the file system journal. The namenode keeps all of the filesystem layout information (files,blocks, directories,permissions,etc) and the block locations.The filesystem layout is persisted on disk and the block locations are kept solely in memory.When a client opens a file,the namenode tells the client the locations of all the blocks in the file;the client then no longer needs to communicate with the namenode for data transfer.

Comment: thanks for the info..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Namenode is one of the java process running in a hadoop cluster. This has the responsibility to manage the metadata associated with the filesystem. So this is also called as the master node or the core node of the hadoop's file system known as Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). Namenode stores the metadata in memory as well as in disk. For frequent access, RAM will be faster, but when the machine fails or when the power goes off, the data in the RAM will be cleared. So it keeps a copy of the metadata in the disk also. The data in the disk will be stored as two files. One is *FSImage* and the other is *editlog*.

The complete metadata upto the last checkpoint will be stored in the FSImage and the recent transactions will be stored in the editlog. As the size of the editlog increases or after a certain predefined time or after a particular number of operations, the editlog will be merged to the FSImage and a new FSImage will be created. In this way, the editlog will always remain as a small file and hence the operations with editlog will be also faster.

The process of merging the FSImage and editlog to create a new FSImage is known as *Checkpointing*